# make a correct dictionary from dataframe groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take this `groupby` structure:

`max_time = df_deh.groupby(['client_id','acc_number'])['time'].max()`

This is its format:

```
client_id  acc_number
0          885020       2019-12-12 19:38:00
           889942       2020-12-21 14:31:39
1          896967       2020-12-15 16:25:52
2          913756       2020-11-11 15:18:17
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I need to make a `dictionary` from it. The `keys` should be the merge of `client_id` and `acc_number` values (preferably with a `-` in between), and the key `items`, the `datetime` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_dict` and then create the keys in the format you want:

```py
{f'{k[0]}-{k[1]}': v for k, v in max_time.to_dict().items()}

{'0-885020': Timestamp('2019-12-12 19:38:00'), '0-889942': Timestamp('2020-12-21 14:31:39'), '1-896967': Timestamp('2020-12-15 16:25:52'), '2-913756': Timestamp('2020-11-11 15:18:17')}
```